# SELECT multiple instances of a row where they might have the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to be able to select some customer details, then select the customer address details, now these customer address details also include previous addresses, and some customers have up to 3 addresses (including previous) and some only one.

I want to select the customer from the customer db, then the customer address(es) from the address db, and load up to 3 of the addresses, per customer, on the same row.

Customer DB:

```
   |   name  |   value    |   num |SecondName|    Date      |  
   | James   |   HEX124   |   1   |  Carl    |   11022020   |  
   | Jack    |   JEU836   |   4   |  Smith   |   19042020   |   
   | Mandy   |   GER234   |   33  |  Jones   |   09042020   |
```

Address DB

```
   |   Address            |   value    | PostCode  |  
   |   1 Smith street     |   HEX124   |  LN18HB   |      
   |   12 fellow garden   |   GER234   |  LN18JL   |   
   |   8 Long street      |   HEX124   |  FF23F2   |      
   |   8 Big road         |   HEX124   |  FWF4GW   |      
   |   89 Kings avenue    |   GER234   |  HH29DD   |   
   |   Roadhouse Cottage  |   JEU836   |  FK28DD   |
```

The 'value' column inside the Customer DB is the customers unique value, this value is also used in the Address DB to assign up to 3 addresses to this one specific customer

My SQL Below:

```
SELECT c.name, c.value, c.num, c.secondname, c.date,
 a.address, a.value, a.postcode,
 a2.address, a2.value, a2.postcode,
 a3.address, a3.value, a3.postcode 
FROM Customers c

INNER JOIN Address a ON a.value = c.value.     //first address
INNER JOIN Address a2 ON a2.value = c.value    //second address
INNER JOIN Address a3 ON a3.value = c.value    //third address
```

This returns as many rows for each customer, as as many addresses they have, and it will repeat the same address 3 times for them:

Result:

```
   | James   |   HEX124   |   1   |  Carl    |   11022020  |   1 Smith street     |   HEX124   |  LN18HB      |   1 Smith street     |   HEX124   |  LN18HB    |   1 Smith street     |   HEX124   |  LN18HB   |      
   | James   |   HEX124   |   1   |  Carl    |   11022020  |   8 Long street      |   HEX124   |  FF23F2        |   8 Long street      |   HEX124   |  FF23F2   |   8 Long street      |   HEX124   |  FF23F2   |
```

As you can see, the results above just repeat the same address for the customer, James will have 3 rows, Mandy 2 rows, and Jack 1 row (1 row per address)

So I tried adding this in, hoping it would read a different address, or return a null value if they don't have 3 addresses:

```
WHERE a.address <> a2.address   //Saying the addresses must not be the same, but this loads nothing when I run the SQL
AND   a.address <> a3.address
AND   a2.address <> a3.address
```

But this returns 0 results

Desired result:

```
   | James   |   HEX124   |   1   |  Carl    |   11022020     |   1 Smith street     |   HEX124   |  LN18HB    |   8 Long street      |   HEX124   |  FF23F2   |   8 Big road         |   HEX124   |  FWF4GW   |    
   | Jack    |   JEU836   |   4   |  Smith   |   19042020     |   Roadhouse Cottage  |   JEU836   |  FK28DD    |   
   | Mandy   |   GER234   |   33  |  Jones   |   09042020     |   12 fellow garden   |   GER234   |  LN18JL    |   89 Kings avenue    |   GER234   |  HH29DD   |
```

As you can see in my desired result, I am loading each customer once, with ALL of their previous address(es) onto the end of their column, some customers will have either 1, 2, or 3 addresses,

Comment: If there are 4 (or more) addresses, what determines what 3 addresses should be returned?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you are after here is a pivot, but on the value of a `ROW_NUMBER`. I *assume* you have some kind of always ascending key for the addresses, so you can determine the most recent ones. I also use a Cross tab (Conditional Aggregation) as it is far less restrictive that the `PIVOT` operator:

```sql
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT c.[name],
           c.[value],
           c.num,
           c.secondname,
           c.[date],
           a.address,
           a.[value] AS addressvalue,
           a.postcode,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.[value] ORDER BY a.idcolumn DESC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.Customer c
         JOIN dbo.Address a ON a.[value] = c.[value])
SELECT R.[name],
       R.[value],
       R.num,
       R.secondname,
       R.[date],
       MAX(CASE R.RN WHEN 1 THEN R.address END) AS address1,
       MAX(CASE R.RN WHEN 1 THEN R.addressvalue END) AS addressvalue1,
       MAX(CASE R.RN WHEN 1 THEN R.postcode END) AS postcode1,
       MAX(CASE R.RN WHEN 2 THEN R.address END) AS address2,
       MAX(CASE R.RN WHEN 2 THEN R.addressvalue END) AS addressvalue2,
       MAX(CASE R.RN WHEN 2 THEN R.postcode END) AS postcode2,
       MAX(CASE R.RN WHEN 3 THEN R.address END) AS address3,
       MAX(CASE R.RN WHEN 3 THEN R.addressvalue END) AS addressvalue3,
       MAX(CASE R.RN WHEN 3 THEN R.postcode END) AS postcode3       
FROM RNs R
GROUP BY c.[name],
         c.[value],
         c.num,
         c.secondname,
         c.[date];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can utilize Row_Number(). ie:


with addresses (AddrNo, [Value], Address, PostCode) as
(
  Select row_number() over (partition by [value] order by Address, PostCode),
     [Value], Address, PostCode
)
SELECT c.name, c.value, c.num, c.secondname, c.date,
 max(case when a.AddrNo=1 then a.address end) as Address1, 
 max(case when a.AddrNo=1 then a.[Value] end) as Value1, 
 max(case when a.AddrNo=1 then a.PostCode end) as PostCode1, 
 max(case when a.AddrNo=2 then a.address end) as Address2, 
 max(case when a.AddrNo=2 then a.[Value] end) as Value2, 
 max(case when a.AddrNo=2 then a.PostCode end) as PostCode2, 
 max(case when a.AddrNo=3 then a.address end) as Address3, 
 max(case when a.AddrNo=3 then a.[Value] end) as Value3, 
 max(case when a.AddrNo=3 then a.PostCode end) as PostCode3 
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Addresses a ON a.[value] = c.[value]
group by c.name, c.value, c.num, c.secondname, c.date;
```

Note: This is only one of the ways to do it. There are other ways which might be easier.